# how to set mongo objectId field to null or empty or even delete the field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**My Modal :**

```
{
  "name":{type:String,required:true},
  "category":{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:"Category"}
}
```

I have a document created using this modal and the document looks like:

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("5dsfkjh2r74dsjdhf3r4f"),
  "name":"demo 1",
  "category":ObjectId("5ae9dlkj32nds6n37cj23")
}
```

If I try to change the category field, for eg:

- `document.category = ''`
- `document.category = null`
- `document.category = undefined`

I'm getting the following error:

> Cast toObjectId failed ...

I need to unset the `"category"` field to `null` or `empty` or even delete it. **How to do that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `unsetting` the document

```
document.update({_id: "5dsfkjh2r74dsjdhf3r4f"}, {$unset: {category: 1 }});
```

or

```
document.update({_id: ObjectId("5dsfkjh2r74dsjdhf3r4f")}, {$unset: {category: 1 }});
```

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectId` should be a 24 length string which I guess your `id` is not. That's why mongo cannot convert it into valid `ObjectId`.

One solution would be to generate 24 character valid `ObjectId` for category field.
Other would be to set `category` as a simple `String` instead of `ObjectId`

Comment: It is not the original id..its for example purpose.By the way i need to delete or unset the object Id field to null.

Comment: "blank" value (in other words - logically set to empty) is ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")

Answer (score 0):

Use Below line
     document.category = new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('');